# Facebook audience network does not log impressions in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

We have integrated the Audience Network Facebook SDK to our android app.

When testing locally, the ads are requested and filled properly.

When the app was released to production, impressions numbers are very less as compared to the fill rate. Our fill rate is very high but the dashboard is showing 0 impressions.

Using our own analytic tools, we are 100% sure that users are receiving and viewing ads. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this issue?

Comment: I didn't find anything specific related to the this problem but my speculation was that I was not getting impressions because users were not seeing the ads. To fix this I preloaded the ads before rendering the UI